# string bytesize to hex

Tags: ruby, string, hex, byte

I was trying to convert the bytesize to hex string in ruby.
I tried various combinations of pack/unpack/chr/hex to no avail.

Here is what I managed to comeup with,

```
"1".bytesize.chr.to_s.split.pack('a4') => "\x01\x00\x00\x00"
```

As you know this wont work for larger strings, for example,

```
"11111111".bytesize.chr().to_s.split.pack('a4') => "\b\x00\x00\x00"
```

where first byte is expected to be `\x0B`, and

```
"testtttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt".bytesize.chr.to_s.split.pack('a4') 
# => ".\x00\x00\x00"
```

which is wrong.

i.e, just the opposite of this, [Unpack 4 bytes to a signed integer](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/94529), where, if the `<string>.bytesize` is `4294967295`, it should be `"\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF"`.

Comment: Don't make it overly complicated: `"1".bytesize` is `1` and `"11111111".bytesize` is `8`. Why do you expect the latter to result in `\x0B\x00\x00\x00`?

Comment: that is a part of the problem, the result would be concatenated to an Intel x64 JMP instruction to become "\xE9\x0B\x00\x00\x00", which later gets executed.

Comment: Can you explain the conversion process in detail? `"\b"` is `00001000` (binary) and  `"\x0B"` is `00001011`. Where do the two extra bits come from?

Comment: fair enough, is it possible to make "\x0b"?

Comment: This one is halfwaythrough. `a = sprintf("%02X",ARGV[0].bytesize)
b = ((a .size % 2 == 0) ? (a) : ("0#{a}")).upcase`